# Regex: Match decimal numerals with no digits before decimal point

Tags: python, regex, expression, leading-zero

I am trying to match decimal numerals with no digits before the decimal point in a string using regex. For example, I have the strings:

```
The dimensions of the object-1 is: 1.4 meters wide, .5 meters long, 5.6 meters high
The dimensions of the object-2 is: .8 meters wide, .11 meters long, 0.6 meters high
```

I want to capture only the decimal numbers without integer digits and prefix leading zeros to them. So my final desired output will be:

```
The dimensions of the object-1 is: 1.4 meters wide, 0.5 meters long, 5.6 meters high
The dimensions of the object-2 is: 0.8 meters wide, 0.11 meters long, 0.6 meters high
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
(\d+)?\.(\d+)
```

This expression is capturing all the decimal numbers such as: `1.4, .5, 5.6, .8, .11, 0.6`.

But I need to capture only decimal numbers without integer digits: `.5, .8, .11`.

Comment: I'd just search for `\([^0-9]\)\(\.[0-9]\)` and replace with `\10\2`.

Comment: Removing the floating-point tag: These are not floating-point numbers. “Floating-point” does not mean “is not an integer” or “might or might not be an integer.” It means the point floats. That is, there is an exponent that scales the number, effectively moving the decimal point (or other radix point). “3.4e5” might be considered floating-point, but “floating-point” generally refers to an internal computer format that contains a field to represent the exponent.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind: `(?<!\d)(\.\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a regex substitution with negative look behind for a digit.

Regex - `(?<!\d)(\.\d+)`

- `(?<!\d)` - Checks that no digit before the regex
- `(\.\d+)` - Captures the dot and one or more consecutive digits

Substitution - `0\1`

- `0` - Adds a single zero for the capture
- `\1` - Back reference to the capture group which is the float starts with a dot

[Regex101 Demo for python regex flavour](https://regex101.com/r/ZTgBxL/1)

#### Python code sample

```
import re

string = "The dimensions of the object-1 is: 1.4 meters wide, .5 meters long, 5.6 meters high \nThe dimensions of the object-2 is: .8 meters wide, .11 meters long, 0.6 meters high"
pattern = r"(?<!\d)(\.\d+)"

match = re.search(pattern, string)
new_string = re.sub(pattern, "Number: 0\\1", string)

print(new_string)
```

Comment: @Animeartist, I updated the answer for python regex syntax